# Vuetify v-list-group change active append-icon

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I try to change append-icon depending on group status (open/close). I tryed to set, but it's dosen't work:

```
v-list-group(
        color="success"
        @click:append="this.marker = !this.marker"
        :append-icon="marker ? 'add' : 'remove'")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oYmM.png)

Sorry for the incomplete code:
(It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details)
**Pug**

```
  v-list(expand, dense, nav)

//1 list lvl
    template(v-for="item in test")
      v-list-item(
        v-if="!item.categories",
      )
        v-list-item-title {{ item.id }}. {{ item.block }}
      v-list-group(
        v-else,
        @click="marker = !marker",
        :append-icon="marker ? 'add' : 'remove'"
      )
        template(#activator)
          v-list-item-content
            v-list-item-title {{ item.id }}. {{ item.block }}

//2 list lvl
        template(v-for="subItem in item.categories")
          v-list-item(
            v-if="!subItem.elements",
          )
            v-list-item-title {{ subItem.id }}. {{ subItem.name }}
          v-list-group(
            v-else,
            :append-icon="marker ? 'add' : 'remove'",
            @click="marker = !marker"
          )
          ....

//3 list lvl ...
```

Comment: this.marker = !this.marker - no this, i guess

Comment: Don't use "this" in the template.

Comment: Ye you are right. But if I use marker = !marker the value dosen't change. I tried to use method, but it's dosen't work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
<v-list-group
   color="success"
   @click="marker = !marker"
   :append-icon="marker ? 'add' : 'remove'">
</v-list-group>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but the icons changed in all groups. I only need to change the icon in the selected group.

Comment: How do you select a group. Can you add the code for that in your question?

Comment: You can add a marker key to every object inside the array and use that on click event. So now you're click event will be like `@click="item.marker = !item.marker"`